# Langchain Load with String

Tags: string, langchain

```
from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader
# Create the TextLoader object using the file path
Loader = tl('data.txt')
```

I want to use a langchain with a string instead of a txt file, is this possible?

```
def get_response(query):
    #print(query)
    result = index.query(query)
    result = str(result)
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Although your question doesn't provide enough information about what you want to achieve; consider that the data for your string must come from somewhere (a PDF file, a URL, a text file, and HTML, a YouTube video etc.).

Having said that, I'll assume that you want to perform a similarity search query on the texts you loaded to retrieve the most relevant texts and output a string. Try this:

```
from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader
# Create the TextLoader object using the file path
Loader = tl('data.txt')

document = loader.load()
```

Here, `document` is a Document object (all LangChain loaders output this type of object). This Document object is a list, where each list item is a dictionary with two keys: `page_content:` which is a string, and `metadata:` which is another dictionary containing information about the document (source, page, URL, etc. they depend on the type of loader you used).

To extract only the text content of `document`, try this after loading the file:

```
text_string = document[0].page_content
```

Then you can use `text_string` for your downstream processing.

If you want to output the query's result as a string, keep in mind that LangChain retrievers give a Document object as output. Therefore, your function should look like this:

```
def get_response(query):
    #print(query)
    result = index.query(query)
    result_text = result[0].page_content
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this code

```py
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.schema.document import Document


def get_text_chunks_langchain(text):
    text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=500, chunk_overlap=100)
    docs = [Document(page_content=x) for x in text_splitter.split_text(text)]
    return docs


def main():
    text = "I want to use a langchain with a string instead of a txt file, is this possible?"
    docs = get_text_chunks_langchain(text)
    print(docs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you, I modified the character splitter with the TokenTextSplitter, and it worked well for me.